# Xamarin Android release mode crash

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have an application that run on Google Tango device Android 4.4.2.
In debug mode the application work fine. 
In release mode after start, the application crash.
This is the log:

[log.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6CXftmuFCxzX2ZRcU1lbWJfaWM)

I use Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin Android 4.3.0.784

Comment: log clearly says where is the error: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
03-21 07:30:13.256: I/MonoDroid(5103):   at XPAD.Document.JobsManager.ChangeJobView`

Comment: If I try with other device, I don't have errors

Comment: The `other devices` can use different Android version for example, so it's just OK. If you want it to run on current device, you have to fix the error.

Comment: I solved the error, but now I have another error: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6CXftmuFCxzbnpWTURXU0RxaWM)

Comment: 1. If you solved it, then provide a solution. 2. If you have another problem, then post another question.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I removed the instruction to check what happen, and I get the new crash

Comment: Your log does not contain the error itself. Only the stacktrace.